# Add a context Menu to File Browser

Tags: android, android-file

I recently installed a Real Player on my Android. If I long press on any image on the file browser. I get Context Menu of either opening the image in a Gallery or a Real Player image viewer.

Can somebody provide me a pointer on how to achieve this functionality of showing the additional context menu of File selection.

thanks

Comment: Okay I found it. You have to actually bind the activity to appropriate view. In my case I would have to use ListActivity and call registerForContextMenu() and create the menu in onCreateContextMenu. I hope this is what I need to do. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on Android's dev guide for [creating a context menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu). Its a great starting point for becoming familiar with how to code them.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on what I want. I know how to create the ContextMenu. What I was interested in how to get handle to the FileListView, so that I can register my Menu with the view.